# How to add a number row to the android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

In my app I need to **add a number row to the Android keyboard**, it is possible?, how?

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about an edittext, then you probably should select an input type for it in your layout with numbers, maybe something like `inputType="numbers|text"`

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the keyboard layout, Keyboards may display different layouts based on the input type you provide with the input field. You'll just need to provide the correct `android:inputType` and let the Keyboard handle it for you.

Also as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html), you can't mix classes together but classes may be combined with variations and flags to indicate desired behaviors. So setting `inputType` to `number|text` will not work and will only display a numeric keypad.

There are two tricks which might work on some Keyboards:

1. Using the `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`

**OR**

2. Hiding the suggestions bar using
   `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)`